# Flashed wrong recovery on a QTAB with no bootloader or fastboot. What can I do?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, bootloader

Hey guys I was just tinkering, and it was stupid of me not to take a backup of any kind. Anyway, QTAB doesn't have a bootloader or fastboot menu. When I try adb reboot bootloader or fastboot, it goes to back to recovery. Now the problem with recovery is I cant use it. Home button makes selection go up and power key does nothing.. and cwm is not touch supported.

I have the stock system.img but no stock recovery. I could try another twrp recovery. But that's what i want to know how to do it.

I've googled and tried various stuff. no luck

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact device model you have I can only tell you to go to the [**website and download the appropriate firmware**](http://qtab.com/index.php?id=18). Get the right file depending on your model number and read the instructions for flashing the stock firmware. This will give you a complete stock tablet back (system.img / recovery.img / boot.img etc).

The instructions seem pretty straight forward even though the procedure is a little bit weird...anyway:

Software needed: [**PhoenixSuit**](http://www.qtab.com/firmwares/PhoenixSuit_EN.msixx)

> Step 1 :Open PhoenixSuit application
>
> Step 2: Choose firmware tab
>
> Step 3: Select the image file from your computer
>
> Step 4:Unplug the qtab + Click upgrade
>
> You  will see this message : "Upgrade Firmware to Device?" Press Yes
>
> Then you will see this message "No Device attached!" - Press Ok
>
> And press ok for the third message also
>
> 1. Now long press your power button for atleast 10 seconds
> 2. Press one hardware key except the power button and do not release
> 3. Connect the device to the computer
> 4. Click power key for about 10 times
> 5. Release all keys and the device will upgrade
>
> If it didn't work, repeat these 5 steps
>   Instructions taken from [**here**](http://www.qtab.com/firmwares/flashing%20steps.doc).

Comment: thanks for responding. I've tried what u r suggesting, but since the tab starts up in recovery only, its not showing in phoenixsuit. says no device connected. I'll keep trying incase it works.
btw, do u know how to get input keyevent to work in adb?
i tried `adb shell` `input keyevent 26`   but it says input not found